# Unable to retrieve data from database through JDBC query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I trying to make a connection to my DDBB in order to print all the columns from a table but I keep getting Null.

I have checked the connection parameters and everything seems correct.

I'm thinking that maybe there is something wrong with my query statement:

```java
public List<Palabra> getTodos() throws SQLException {
     SQLConexion con = new SQLConexion();
     listaPalabras = new ListaPalabras();
     
     if(con.ConectarBasedeDatos()) {
         try{
             Statement stmt = con.getConnection().createStatement();  
             ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PALABRA"); 
             while(rs.next()) {
                 Palabra pal = new Palabra(rs.getInt("idPalabra"), rs.getString("palabra"), rs.getInt("dificultad")); //These are the columns that I need to print.
                 listaPalabras.addPalabra(pal); //adding the results to the list
             }
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         { 
             System.out.println(e);
         }  
     }
     else {
         return null;
     }
     
     con.DesconectarBasedeDatos();

     return listaPalabras.getListaPalabras();
 }
```

Comment: Sounds like `con.ConectarBasedeDatos()` returns `false`. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Hi Mark, can you please tell me what info would you need? I have edited a bit the main message.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre], that is, the minimal code (without any unnecessary stuff) to reproduce the problem. As I said, it sounds like `con.ConectarBasedeDatos()` is returning `false`, so at least provide the code from `SQLConexion` as well.

Comment: Basically Java can't access the database, this might be many things, connection string or credentials would be the first place I'd look. If you are absolutely positive this is correct test whether you can connect to database from some client like DBeaver. There might also be a networking issue involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by adding the MySQL Connector to the libraries so indeed there was no connection with the database because of this.

Novice error.

Thanks a lot for your time.